# What is the GCS equivalent of the blobstore "Create_upload_url"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We currently use blobstore.create_upload_url to create upload urls to be used on the frontend see [Uploading a blob](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob).
However, with the push toward Google Cloud Storage (GCS) by Google, I'd like to use GCS instead of the blobstore. We use currently blobstore.create_upload_url but I can't find anything equivalent in the GCS documentation. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to upload files to GCS from the frontend?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Take a look at [GCS File Upload](http://romannowicki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gae/file-upload.html#file-upload) You can still use blobstore.create_upload_url for GCS it's described in documentation in here: [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)

Comment: Thanks @manRo so specifying a bucketname is all that needs to happen for the blob to go to gcs instead of blobstore? Perhaps put this in the answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Yes that's correct if you will provide bucket name file will be uploaded to GCS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will provide `gs_bucket_name` to `blobstore.create_upload_url` file will be stored in GCS instead of blobstore, this is described in official documentation: [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)

```
blobstore.create_upload_url(
                success_path=webapp2.uri_for('upload'),
                gs_bucket_name="mybucket/dest/location")
```

You can take a look at simple upload handler implementation made in webapp2

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import webapp2
import cloudstorage as gcs


class Upload(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    """Upload handler
    To upload new file you need to follow those steps:

    1. send GET request to /upload to retrieve upload session URL
    2. send POST request to URL retrieved in step 1
    """
    def post(self):
        """Copy uploaded files to provided bucket destination"""
        fileinfo = self.get_file_infos()[0]
        uploadpath = fileinfo.gs_object_name[3:]
        stat = gcs.stat(uploadpath)

        # remove auto generated filename from upload path 
        destpath = "/".join(stat.filename.split("/")[:-1])

        # copy file to desired location with proper filename 
        gcs.copy2(uploadpath, destpath)
        # remove file from uploadpath
        gcs.delete(uploadpath)

    def get(self):
        """Returns URL to open upload session"""

        self.response.write(blobstore.create_upload_url(
            success_path=uri_for('upload'),
            gs_bucket_name="mybucket/subdir/subdir2/filename.ext"))
```

Comment: also, note that GCS has this too, hidden in the xml section of the api. see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object